# JavaScript play/pause audio button, change class and create auto loop

Tags: javascript, playback

My code works like this: When I click play the class "play" changes to class "pause", but when I click on pause it doesn't change to "play" class.

And second question will be how to make auto loop for audio.

My code:

HTML:

```
<a class="playback">
                <span id="toggle" class="play"></span>
            </a> 
            <audio>
             <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/venga.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                <source src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/venga.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
            </audio>
```

CSS:

```
.play {
        background: url('img/play.png') no-repeat;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        padding: 24px 45px 3px 0px;
        margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    }
    .pause {
        background: url('img/pause.png') no-repeat;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        padding: 24px 45px 3px 0px;
        margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    }
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".playback").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
        if (song.paused)
            song.play();
        else
            song.pause();
    });
});
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle').bind("click", function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "play")
            $(this).attr("class", "pause");
        else
            $(this).attr("class", "play");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors for the class changing code. I tried and it works well with your code.

Comment: No errors, but the class "pause" dont changes back to class "play"

Comment: Can you setup a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yeah, i test on fiddle its working, seems my script intersects with other scripts on my website...

Comment: How about with the loop function it is possible to add in this script?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving inspiration for a beginner like me..
the script seems work in my html page, with iOS simulator.

perhaps you include 2 jquery version? i'm not sure where's the problem with your code..